Bayesian Inference of a Gaussian Process with a Continuous-time Obervations
In many books about Bayesian inference based on Gaussian process, it is assumed that one can only observe a set of data/signals at discrete points. This is a very realistic assumption. However, in some theoretical models we may want to assume that a continuum of data/signals. In this case, I find it very difficult to write the joint distribution matrix. Can anyone offer some guidance or textbooks dealing with such a situation? Thank you in advance for your help!
To be specific, consider the most simple iid case. Let $\theta_x$ be the unknown true states of interest where $x\in[0,1]$ is a continuous lable. The prior belief is that $\theta_x$ follows a Gaussian process. A continuum of data points $s_x$ are observed which are generated according to $s_x=\theta_x+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is the Gaussian error. How can I derive the posterior belief as a Gaussian process? I know intuitively it is very simimlar to the discrete case, but I just cannot figure out how to rigorous prove it.
